# SciPy interp2d Memory Error, looking for alternative

Tags: numpy, scipy, interpolation

I am converting an MATLAB program to a Python program using NumPy and SciPy and I am still new to it. In part of the program, I have the following MATLAB code:

```
tImg(:,:,1) = interp2(x,y,Img(:,:,1),Tx,Ty,'cubic');
```

All parameters in the interp2 method are 298x142 double.

So I tried to convert it to the following Python code:

```
tImg[:, :, 0] = (scipy.interpolate.interp2d(x, y, img[:, :, 0], kind='cubic'))(Tx, Ty)
```

I am given MemoryError in the interp2d method. The MATLAB code runs fine. I have read through the interpolation documentation but I don't seem to find a solution.

I run the code above with 3GB memory, with scipy 0.16.0.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the problem is that `Tx` and `Ty` mean different things for MATLAB's `interp2` function and `scipy.interpolate.interp2d`.

In the MATLAB `interp2` function, `Tx` and `Ty` would be 2D arrays that specify the x,y coordinates for *each individual* output point, so the result would be a vector with the same shape as `Tx` and `Ty`, i.e.:

```
timg(i, j, 1) = interp2(x, y, Img(i, j, 1), Tx(i, j),Ty(i, j), 'cubic');
```

In `scipy.interpolate.interp2d`, `Tx` and `Ty` should be 1D vectors that specify the x and y coordinates for the rows and columns for a *regular mesh* over which the interpolant is to be evaluated, i.e.:

```
timg[i, j, 0] = intp(Tx[i], Ty[j])
```

I suspect that you are passing the coordinates of *every* point you want to interpolate at, in which case you will get an `(nx*ny, nx*ny)` output. If `nx = 298` and `ny = 142` then you would generate an `(42316, 42316)` array. Assuming it contains 64 bit floats, that would take up about 14GB of memory in total.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, even when I try without Tx and Ty, i.e. `scipy.interpolate.interp2d(x, y, img[:, :, 0], kind='cubic')`, I still get memory error. So I suspect it is related to internal implementation of scipy. Therefore I am seeking an alternative which can achieve the same output.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem you're describing. Could you turn your description into a reproducible test case by showing how you would generate some fake data for `x`, `y` and `img`?